# Delete files/ folders with .nfs files

Tags: directory, nfs, rm

A lot of time when I delete a folder, it says cannot be deleted because of `.nfs` files.

```
Error - Device or resource busy
```

How can I delete a folder ignoring these errors (is there any flag in `rm` command)? Or I would have to find out the process using it, and first kill that process?

In that case how can I make it work to remove entire directories?

Comment: You could try running `fuser /path/to/.nfs` to check which process is using the .nfs file.

Comment: what difference would it make than using lsof ?

Comment: For this, none I guess. But I don't understand why you're asking that.

Comment: I want to use some script which deletes all files/folders inside a directory, and also clear up any .nfs files present.

Comment: Can you give an example of a .nfs file name? NFS commonly uses .nfs### files for internal record keeping, for example (where ### is some long string of digits). Also would be useful to know if NFS is involved, either the file system you are using is NFS mounted on your host, or if it is NFS exported to some other host.

Comment: Thanks @mtak fuser worked nicely! I will show example in a new answer . . elsewhere as this Q marked as duplicate.

Comment: Example of using fuser and successful remove here: a tracker-extract process was holding files open on the nfs disk. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231074/removed-a-vagrant-file-and-now-i-see-nfs0000000000b869e300000001/537840#537840

Comment: @Peter Example of file name ```.nfs00000000018d307a00000369```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove whole folder with `rm -rf <folder name>`, where `r` means *recursive* and `f` *forcefully*. See man page of `rm` for better understanding.

But if the error *Device or resource busy* is coming that means that the folder is in use by some process. So you first need to find that process and kill it, and then you can remove the folder.

Comment: Will rm -rf able to delete the files even if they say "Device or Resource busy" ?

Comment: Yes, And just try it on your set-up and check it out.

Comment: Good suggestion. I just tried. It doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: No, you can't delete `.nfsXXX` files. Or more precisely, you can delete them, but they'll come back immediately. You need to close the program that has them open, and that program could be running on any client that has this directory mounted over NFS.